# RegEx Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am very new to RegEx and have a very simple question.

I am trying to see specific average page load performance in Google Analytics and I use `|` expression to add each specific pages. I type this into "filter" section on Dashboard:

```
webistename/|websitename/video/video-profinet-communication/|websitename/?s=house+of+mass|websitename/article/house-of-mass-fancy-coriolis-mass-flow-meters/|websitename/category/devices/flow/
```

However, it shows me a table which sorts descending page load time instead of giving me these 5 specific pages.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Put brackets around the clauses you want to OR, and escape the ? and + symbols.

Comment: If you mean this `website/|website/video/video-profinet-communication/|website/s=houseofmass|website/article/house-of-mass-fancy-coriolis-mass-flow meters/|website/category/devices/flow/` not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^webistename/$|^websitename/video/video-profinet-communication/$|^websitename/\?s=house+of+mass$|^websitename/article/house-of-mass-fancy-coriolis-mass-flow-meters/$|^websitename/category/devices/flow/$
```

- ^ refers to starts with
- $ = ends with
- \ = for special characters (?)